# Select Case for sheet.Number > 4

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that will contain ready to use sheets to work with. Someone chooses with a UserForm a set of defined sheets to work with. "Project A" or "Project B" etc.

By choosing one of the sets there will be written in cell from sheet4.range("i4")  for ex. **"Project A"**. With each new start there will be shown only that set chosen with UserFrom. I need to make one short fix for all additional sheets added by the users.

In my select case expression I need to make a statement for tables bigger than **sheet4.**   So sheet5, sheet6 etc.

How should I write that one line of code in:
for ex. **case "Project A"** that all new sheets with **sheetX > sheet4** will be set veryhidden?

```
'First part of code is unimportant
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Step 1: Unhide All Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        'Step 2:  Loop to next worksheet
    Next ws

    'in Range I4 Table 4 = "Projekt A" or "Projekt B" etc.
    Select Case sheet4.Range("i4").Text
        Case "Project A"
            'Step 3:  Hide two defined sheets sheet("start") and sheet3 and all bigger than sheet.4 
     (sheet.5, sheet.6...)
            Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
            sheet3.Visible = xlVeryHidden
 'I need here to write that all table bigger than 4 will be set =xlVeryHidden
        Case "Project B"
    End Select

    Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    sheet1.Visible = xlVeryHidden

    Call sheet1.auo_open

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear... You take text from I4 cell and do some actions. What is Tabelle? What are connections?

Comment: You're right, just added few rows with comments. I need to write a check direct in code by: **case "Project A"**. to set all table bigger than 4 as xlVeryHidden

Comment: You didn't answer what is Tabelle? Is it some variable? Is it sheet's programmatic name?

Comment: "Tabelle" is "Sheet" in the german version of excel... simply see it like that -> "Tabelle1" is the initial code name for "Sheet1" in VBA (so just the naming here)

Comment: a short fix would be to change the code name of the sheets 1 to 4. assuming that the workbook is used only in the same language, new sheets always will have a code name like `Tabelle***`. Now run all sheets and check for the codename and if it starts with `Tabelle` simply hide it...

Comment: So i get it. I change all sheets that already exists(german TabelleX) in some other names like ProjectA1, A2 etc. Then only new sheets will be name like "TabelleX" and those will be defined to be selected and hidden. But how can i do that? How should i write it?

Comment: Are you just trying to loop through sheets and hide them?

Comment: yes but only newly added. And they are named sheetX

Comment: You could use the `Right()` function to pull the last digit or two of the `ws.Name` and check whether that is greater than 4

Comment: You’d use `isNumeric()` to see if 2 digits or 1 is the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an simple example of hiding worksheets you don't want users to see, leaving specific worksheets visible.  This code will allow users to unhide the worksheets by going to `Home_Cells_Format_Visibility_Hide & Unhide_Unhide Sheet`. But, If you use `xlsheetveryhidden`, the user can't unhide the worksheets

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not (ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2" _
    Or ws.Name = "Sheet3" Or ws.Name = "Sheet4") Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next ws
```

Edit: In case someone would like to use Select Case

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"

        Case Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: congrats on determining what the op was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jeeped, puzzles are great for helping dementia.

Comment: ... or OCD but not as easy to ,walk away from.